# Need to copy set of selective directories and its files using DOS commands or batch programming

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a folder called abc.  In this folder i have around 50 sub folders.  The nomenclature of these folders are in the form of mmddyy, so each folder is unique.  Now, suppose i need to copy all the folders along with its files for the month 08*.*, how i will do it using dos command or batch programming?

Comment: Are you _really_ using "DOS"? The command line in Windows has nothing to do with "DOS" (or MS-DOS)

Answer (score 0):

Implying you're actually using Windows, not DOS (FreeDOS, MSDOS, etc).

- Use [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) on modern Windows:

  ```
  robocopy /s "d:\abc" "d:\somewhere" 08*.*
  ```

  A lot of extra info is output to console which can be suppressed by adding `/njh /njs`
- Use [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) which is deprecated but still present in modern Windows:

  ```
  xcopy /s "d:\abc\08*.*" "d:\somewhere\\"
  ```

Both commands skip empty folders by default, to include them add `/e`